# Play store search can not find application on a certain device

Tags: android

The application is not shown when user searches to download on Google Play from a certain device.

The device model is 'Primo_ef3' which is listed in Supported Device list under Device Compatibility section in Play Google developer console. Other devices working fine.

The device also supports my app features.

[image]

Comment: There might be any feature that the app uses but device might not have it. You may also check for supported screen resolutions in manifest.

Comment: If the device doesn't support the app features then it couldn't be listed as a supported device in Google Play Developer Console. @random

Comment: Yes you're right about app feature. Can you check if it is because of any filter http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html like a country targeting or priced status?

Comment: I have checked this link and rechecked my Developer Console. All seems to be fine. All same/similar devices working fine with same configuration except Primo_ef3 model. @random

Comment: You should then contact google support and check with them

Comment: Probably you are right. @random